# Why is IIS allowing only 3 connections at the time?

Tags: iis, .net, application-pools

I have installed IIS (Version 10.0.10.586.0) on Windows 10, I am trying to do some stress tests locally with jmeter creating a lot of get requests simultaneusly but jmeter is being allowed to do only 3 requests at the time.

[image]

The url jmeter is hitting (localhost:80/test) takes 5 seconds to respond and there are only 3 responses every 5 seconds.

I have tried changing the ASP configurations on my IIS Management console (Threads per preprocessor limit) but there is no difference, I have changed also the number of workers and that does make a difference but that's not what I need.

How can I make one worker process to handle/allow more that three requests at the time?

I'm using a .NET v4.5 application pool.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Be as precise as possible about version, edition, service pack level, license level, and so on. (See the IIS [license table](http://www.jpelectron.com/sample/WWW%20and%20HTML/IIS-%20OS%20Version%20Limits.htm).)

Comment: Windows 10 Home Single Language 64bits

Comment: And you're using IIS, not IIS Express? That should have a 10 connection limitation.

Comment: this is my IIS version http://prntscr.com/ccov8v

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're hitting the license limit for a non-server OS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Scott Forsyth's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/windows-8-iis-8-concurrent-requests-limit), this is a limit set by the Windows licensing team. Below is the information from his blog:

**Windows Vista – IIS 7 Concurrent Requests Limit**

```
|  3 | Home Basic (IIS process activation and HTTP processing only)
|  3 | Home Premium
| 10 | Ultimate, Professional, Enterprise
```

**Windows 7 – IIS 7.5 Concurrent Requests Limit**

```
|  1 | Home Starter
|  1 | Basic
|  3 | Premium
| 10 | Ultimate, Professional, Enterprise
```

**Windows 8 – IIS 8 Concurrent Requests Limit**

```
|  3 | Basic edition
| 10 | Professional, Enterprise
| NA | RT - N/A since IIS does not run on Windows RT
```

> Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2012 allow an unlimited amount of simultaneously requests.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know there was a very low connection limit for non server OS, looks like that is the reason of my 3 connections limit.

Thanks @David Schwartz (see the question comments)

Comment: Mark this as solution if the question doesn't need answering

Comment: I will, but the site won't let me until one more day

Answer (score 1):

in 1993 Microsoft began implementing a hard coded limit to the number of users which could connect to their "server" services running on Windows workstation.   This was right around the time of SQL 4.21 and SNA Server of the same release, both of which were leading the adoption of Windows in the Enterprise.  In the quarter after those upgrades released Microsoft saw an explosion in Server editions of Windows being purchased to underpin SQL, SNA which were then cut back to ten connections. To bring back the connections they had previously? Upgrade to a server edition of Windows.  Curiously, this bit of behavior never made it to the public during the "Microsoft as a Monopoly" discussion

This is a long path to say, IIS on Windows workstation is going to be capped in the number of connections.  On Windows Server it will not.  You can go Apache on workstation, which doesn't have to adhere to Microsoft's policy limit on their server software, or you can move to Windows server.